# What is difference between ExecuteStoreQuery and ExecuteStoreCommand

Tags: c#, entity-framework, executestorequery

In entityframework we can use ExecuteStoreQuery or ExecuteStoreCommand to execute sql queries. So what is difference between them(which scenario it is different)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is clear from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **ExecuteStoredQuery**
>
> Executes a query directly against the data source that returns a
> sequence of typed results.

and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **ExecuteStoreCommand**
>
> Executes an arbitrary command directly against the data source using
> the existing connection.

[Example for ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee358769(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
using (SchoolEntities context =
    new SchoolEntities())
{
    // The following three queries demonstrate 
    // three different ways of passing a parameter.
    // The queries return a string result type.

    // Use the parameter substitution pattern.
    foreach (string name in context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>
        ("Select Name from Department where DepartmentID < {0}", 5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    // Use parameter syntax with object values.
    foreach (string name in context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>
        ("Select Name from Department where DepartmentID < @p0", 5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
    // Use an explicit SqlParameter.
    foreach (string name in context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>
        ("Select Name from Department where DepartmentID < @p0",
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "p0", Value = 5 }))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

[Example for ExecuteStoreCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee358769(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
public class DepartmentInfo
{
    private DateTime _startDate;
    private String _name;
    private Int32 _departmentID;

    public Int32 DepartmentID
    {
        get
        {
            return _departmentID;
        }
        set
        {
            _departmentID = value;
        }
    }
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _startDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value;
        }
    }
}

public static void ExecuteStoreCommands()
{
    using (SchoolEntities context =
        new SchoolEntities())
    {

        int DepartmentID = 21;
        // Insert the row in the Department table. Use the parameter substitution pattern.
        int rowsAffected = context.ExecuteStoreCommand("insert Department values ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})",
                        DepartmentID, "Engineering", 350000.00, "2009-09-01", 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of affected rows: {0}", rowsAffected);

        // Get the DepartmentTest object. 
        DepartmentInfo department = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<DepartmentInfo>
            ("select * from Department where DepartmentID= {0}", DepartmentID).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Name: {1} ", department.DepartmentID, department.Name);

        rowsAffected = context.ExecuteStoreCommand("delete from Department where DepartmentID = {0}", DepartmentID);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of affected rows: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
}
```

Comment: So... The former returns typed results as if they were intances of the classes that EF defines and the latter only executes some code?

Comment: @MVCDS:-  To make it simple I would say that ExecuteStoreQuery method is equivalent to calling the ExecuteReader, however it returns entities :)

Comment: When I use executestorequery and executestorecommand? Could you please give me some example?

Comment: @manaskumar:- Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee358769(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Can I use executestorequery to update something in my Database?

Comment: @manaskumar:- And as I said the ExecuteStoreQuery is equivalent to ExecuteReader so have you used ExecuteReader to update?

Comment: Doesn't work at all for Table-Per-Hierarchy entities.